# Does "transparently" error correcting RAM exist, requiring no host support?

Tags: memory, ecc

As currently standardized, both the motherboard and CPU must support ECC RAM, and annoyingly, Intel (and to a lesser extent AMD) use ECC support to segment the market.

But obviously you could make RAM that transparently performs error correction without the host being aware, by simply speaking regular DDR(n) to the host, and secretly error correcting across its dies. Presumably you lose some functionality in terms of monitoring errors (as I assume JEDEC didn't put anything into the DDR standards for reporting errors as "non-ECC" RAM?), but of course this is possible.

Does such RAM exist, for use in systems that "don't support ECC"?

Edit: A friend pointed out an [award given today](https://safari.ethz.ch/minesh-patel-awarded-an-eth-doctoral-medal/) to an ETH Zürich PhD thesis that discusses on-die error correction in DRAM, a skimming of which seems to indicate that maybe folks are already doing a bit of what I'm suggesting – the key term seems to be "on-die ECC".

Comment: You are aware there are additional ICs on ECC memory, so everyone would pay more, for a feature they might not need. What you describe does not exist.  DDR3 and DDR4 are outdated and no new products would be created, and DDR5, is already too costly.

Comment: Either it exists already or it doesn't. Right now it doesn't. This isn't a bad question on its own, but this site isn't just for any computer question or any good question: it is for specific questions that can be specifically answered. This question needs discussion and open ended conversation, and that happens on other good sites.

Comment: It sounds like you're giving a specific answer (namely, it doesn't exist) that answers my specific yes/no question! How about instead of closing this question, make that an answer?

Comment: This question relates to a similar one... the concept of _universal RAM_. Through the use of a converter chip _(similar what is done with current 'buffered' / 'registered' RAM)_ to translate timing and/or voltage, one or more DDR5 RAM ICs could be placed on a custom PCB allowing it to be used, e.g., as a DDR3 SO-DIMM, or a PC133 RAM DIMM, or for a RAM SIMM for a 1990s-era HP laser printer.

Comment: @music2myear Wouldn't "This doesn't exist, and here are the reasons why" be a specific answer to this person's specific question? Is the issue that this was the wrong StackExchange site in which to ask it, or that it would not be welcome on _any_ StackExchange site?